# How can I fix the error in the Automata FSM?

Tags: javascript, module, fsm, automata

I found a FSM called Automata that looks useful but there is one error that keeps me from using it. It might have something to do with the way the Node module exports?

The FSM is available here:

https://github.com/hyperandroid/Automata

When I debug the test.html file the console shows the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerFSM' of undefined
  (anonymous function)  test1.js:57

Is this just an error I'm getting, can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved. As I learnt more about require imports it was easy to make the corrections and run the project. As is, the Automata package comes with flawed imports.